# reading and printing specific lines based on gender in string from text file (java)

Tags: java, file

what I am trying to do is pick out certain lines in a text file and print them separately based on the gender of the person in the text file. There is the ID, name, gender, and age in that order.

Example line from text file(male): 1 John m 18
Example line from text file(female): 3 Susan f 21

This is the code that I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



class person {
String id;
String name;
String gender;
int age;
  }

public class arrayList3 {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("student.txt"));
    ArrayList<person> studentList = new ArrayList<>(); //all types

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        person p = new person();
        p.id = input.next();
        p.name = input.next();
        p.gender = input.next();
        p.age = input.nextInt();
        studentList.add(p);
      }
   //prints list of female students
   System.out.println("== Female Student List ==");
    for (int k = 0; k < studentList.size(); k++){
        if(studentList.contains("f")){

            System.out.println(studentList.get(k).id +" "+ studentList.get(k).name +" "+ studentList.get(k).gender +" "+ studentList.get(k).age);
        }

    } 
   System.out.println();

   //prints list of male students
   System.out.println("== Male Student List ==");
    for (int k = 0; k < studentList.size(); k++){

        System.out.println(studentList.get(k).id +" "+ studentList.get(k).name +" "+ studentList.get(k).gender +" "+ studentList.get(k).age);

    } 
    input.close();
}


}
```

I tried using an if statement for the female student list but that just doesn't print anything. For the male student list it just prints the whole text file instead of just printing the male students.

Comment: `if (studentList.get(k).gender.equals("F"))...`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Alas! If only they were **all** that simple...(sigh)

Answer (score 0):

Sean,

Your for loop contains this line:

```
if(studentList.contains("f")){
```

But studentList is defined like this:

```
ArrayList<person> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Your the above if statement should never evaluate to true because "f" is a String, and that is not the same type as the contents of the list.

Assuming that person.gender of "f" is what you are trying to filter by, the simplest change to your program to make it work would be to replace the above if statement with:

```
if("f".equals(studentList.get(k).gender)){
```